# Adding postional (well Id) specific data to a table (based on a 96 well plate)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to work with a large data set, that contains csv files that have been exported from graphpad.

[image]

I need to eventually pivot/meld these tables into a long skinny format, but first I need to assign a wellID to each number. (Ignoring the x axis, these should all overlay on a 8x12 grid).  My thought was that I could insert a new column after each column with the same name, [Intermediate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBAUt.png). The hope here is that after melding, all of the Well_Id columns would concatenate into one that brings along the attached data. The problem also being it should also only associate with the newest column directly to it's right.

[image: [final expected layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RFQx.png)]

I'm newer to programming so I wanted to see if I'm going about this the right way, before investing too much time.  Below is a VBA script I started to put together, however it is throwing an error when setting up the placeholder for column + 1 (object required)

```
Sub Assign_Plate_wells()
Dim iLastCol As Integer
Dim nxtcol As Integer

    
    'Counts to the last column and then works backwards
    iLastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For colx = iLastCol To 2 Step -1
        Columns(colx).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
           
            'Supposed to target the header of the newly created column and change the name
            Cells(1, colx).FormulaR1C1 = "Well_ID"
    
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: `nxtcol` is an `Integer`, so you do not use the word `Set` - `Set` is used only for object variables.

Comment: Please don't tag your question with the [tag:r] tag unless your question uses the R programming language.

Comment: All your curves are 8-point?  Can you post a link to a sample file (with any confidential info swapped out)   Prism output is not the best...

Comment: ...and do you have one file per plate?

Comment: Unfortunately this is all external data that we don't have any control over, I agree prism output is not great.  We currently have one file per plate, but there is no pattern to the plate names, so I'm just going to put them in a folder and read that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a one-step approach:

```vb
Sub FormatOutput()
    Const NUM_PTS As Long = 8 'points per curve
    Dim wb As Workbook, wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rngConcs As Range, rngData As Range, cDest As Range, col As Long
    Dim rwDest As Range, r As Long, wellRow As Long, wellCol As Long
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsSrc = ActiveSheet
    Set wsDest = wb.Worksheets("listing") 'for example
    Set rwDest = wsDest.Rows(2)
    
    Set rngConcs = wsSrc.Range("A2").Resize(NUM_PTS)
    wellCol = 1
    Do While Application.CountA(rngConcs) > 0 'loop down the concentration column
        For col = 1 To 20                'loop across the readout columns
            Set rngData = rngConcs.Offset(0, col)
            If Application.CountA(rngData) > 0 Then 'any readout data here?
                For wellRow = 1 To NUM_PTS
                    rwDest.Cells(1).Value = rngConcs.Cells(wellRow).Value
                    rwDest.Cells(2).Value = WellLabel(wellRow, wellCol)
                    rwDest.Cells(3).Value = rngData.Cells(wellRow).Value
                    Set rwDest = rwDest.Offset(1)  'next row on output sheet
                Next wellRow
                wellCol = wellCol + 1 'next plate column
            End If
        Next col
    
        Set rngConcs = rngConcs.Offset(NUM_PTS + 1) 'next concs block (one blank line)
    Loop
End Sub

'return a well label given row and column number
Function WellLabel(rw As Long, col As Long) As String
    WellLabel = Chr(64 + rw) & Format(col, "00")
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Tim I ran this through a dataset and made some changes and it appears that it is prioritizing "A01" as being the top most data instead of reading left to right (column by column).  This led to one set with the top most data (in the center of the plate) being assigned A1. Everything else worked correctly. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's difficult from your screenshot to know what order those blocks should be in - for example is there anything in "Column 1", and how many different dilution sets do you have? If you could mark up your screenshot with overlays showing what part of the plate each readout block is for that would help a lot.